# Access Vba Copy file with part random name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have code in access VBA to copy file form serwer to user path

```
      FromPath = "\\xx.xx.xx.xx\zz.zzzz\" & folder & "\"
            ToPath = "C:\newfolder\" & b & "\"
            File = barkod & ".tif"
            FileCopy FromPath & File, ToPath & File
```

barcode is string

I have file that name is ***barcode_"random alphanumeric characters".tif***
how yo copy this file with random alphanumeric characters in name

this is example of file name:

412355557816_17385084

412355557816_15987047

Code like this isn't working :(
File = master & "_" & "*" & ".tif"

What should be in "*"?

Comment: Can you add more of your code?  Like how are "folder", "b" and "barkod" assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proposal, using dir command to list files matching a certain pattern

```
FromPath = "\\xx.xx.xx.xx\zz.zzzz\" & folder & "\"
ToPath = "C:\newfolder\" & b & "\"
f = Dir(FromPath & barkod & "*.tif")
While f <> ""
    FileCopy FromPath & f, ToPath & f
    f = Dir()
Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` in combination with the wildcard operator `*`

```
Sub testlike()
    barcode = "412355557816*"
    If "412355557816_17385084" Like barcode Then
        Debug.Print "Match"
    End If
End Sub
```